# Server fault issue

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I am trying to link to a specific page within a PDF.

For desktop the URL works with:

https://www.examsolutions.net/papers/edexcel/gcse/nov17/paper2/paper2QUE.pdf#page=3

It takes you to page three, but does not work on mobile. However if I use jQuery

```
if ($(window).width() < 600) {
   $("a").each(function(){
      var newUrl = $(this).attr('href').replace('page=', 'page');
      $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
    });
}
```

The URL is changed to:

https://www.examsolutions.net/papers/edexcel/gcse/nov17/paper2/paper2QUE.pdf#page3

The removeal of the '=' works, but only on iOS. Is there a solution for Android or is it not possible due to Adobe PDF licenseing etc?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hi there, never heard of server fault.com. I'll post there, thanks. Infact I think i've just found my answer there..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpful guidance, I took it all on board and thought I would post back what I actuall did incase someone else needs a breakdown. To be clear, my hosting is a VPS on a LAMP stack running Ubuntu.

1. Repointed the a-record of the old site to the new one.
2. Created a config file in the sites-available folder of apache2
3. Pointed that config file to where I wanted the hosted folder to be, 
   in my case home/www/vhosts/
4. Created a folder in the above in the name of the old website
5. Added the .htaccess file in that folder with the 301 redirect in it.
6. Made the website active my using the a2ensite command
7. Restarted apache

Answer (score 0):

Option A is fine - do that.

It depends what the set up is on your new hosting...

If you have cPanel you can add the old domain as a parked domain - takes 30 seconds to set up - then just point your name servers/DNS the new hosting.

Alternatively you can set up the old site on your new hosting, then do a 301 redirect in the .htaccess file pointing it to your new domain.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/